# How to save assets fast (AssetDatabase.CreateAsset)

Tags: unity-game-engine, bundle, assets

I have generated about 70 000 gameobjects with meshes and materials in a scene. I need to save these meshes and materials in assets. I save assets with AssetDatabase.CreateAsset, but its takes a lot of time (about 24 hours). I save meshes and materials in order to make bundles.

My code generate meshes and materials:

```
public class SaveAssetsUtils
{
static public void Save(string path, GameObject target)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    string materialsPathBase = path + "Materials/";
    string meshesPathBase = path + "Meshes/";

    if (!Directory.Exists(materialsPathBase))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(materialsPathBase);
    else
        FilesUtils.ClearFolder(materialsPathBase);

    int folderIndex = 0;
    string meshesDir = "dir" + folderIndex + "/";
    if (!Directory.Exists(meshesPathBase))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(meshesPathBase);
    else
        FilesUtils.ClearFolder(meshesPathBase);

    if (!Directory.Exists(meshesPathBase + meshesDir))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(meshesPathBase + meshesDir);

    MeshFilter[] meshFilters = target.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>(true);

    ProgressUtil.Progress("Starting save assets", "starting save assets " + meshFilters.Length, 0.323f);

    int indexMesh = 0;
    int indexMaterial = 0;
    int countMeshes = 0;

    int count = meshFilters.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < meshFilters.Length; i++)
    {
        var meshFilter = meshFilters[i];
        var meshRenderer = meshFilter.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

        var materialName = meshRenderer.sharedMaterial.name;
        if (materialName.IndexOf("exists") == -1)
        {
            var pathMaterial = materialsPathBase + "_exists_" + indexMaterial + ".mat";

            meshRenderer.sharedMaterial.name = "_exists_" + indexMaterial;
            UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(meshRenderer.sharedMaterial, pathMaterial);

            indexMaterial++;
        }

        var meshName = meshFilter.sharedMesh.name;
        if (meshName.IndexOf("exists") == -1)
        {
            ProgressUtil.Progress("Save mesh", "save mesh " + indexMesh + " from " + meshFilters.Length, 0.323f + (0.68f / count) * indexMesh );

            var pathMesh = meshesPathBase + meshesDir + "_exists_" + i + ".asset";

            meshFilter.sharedMesh.name = "_exists_" + indexMesh;
            UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(meshFilter.sharedMesh, pathMesh);

            indexMesh++;
            countMeshes++;
        }

        if (countMeshes > 100)
        {
            folderIndex++;
            countMeshes = 0;
            meshesDir = "dir" + folderIndex + "/";
            if (!Directory.Exists(meshesPathBase + meshesDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(meshesPathBase + meshesDir);
        }
    }

    UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code that you're running? 24 hours seems like an excessive amount of time for 70k GameObjects' worth of assets; are you sure you're not accidentally saving too many objects?

Comment: Save 35k meshes takes about 10 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this

I had +3000 objects to save, and I realized 'AssetDatabase.CreateAsset' is Pretty Slow, so I did like this.

```
AssetDatabase.StartAssetEditing();
foreach(.....)
     AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(....)
AssetDatabase.StopAssetEditing();
```

That actually saved me!